# 2 Dropzone on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropzone.js

Currently I have a form with dropzone.js and it works correctly, but the form must be 2 times on the same page, only the styles change when I insert the second form only the first one remains working

I don't know what changes I should make

Currently I have a form with dropzone.js and it works correctly, but the form must be 2 times on the same page, only the styles change when I insert the second form only the first one remains working

I don't know what changes I should make

```js
script

<code>
    var Onyx = {

    defaults: {
        debug: true
    },


    /**
     * Function to print results in the console if the above debug is true
    **/
    log: function() {
        if (Onyx.defaults.debug === true) {
            var argsArray = [],
                printOut = "console.log(args)";

            for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
                argsArray.push("args[" + i + "]");
            }

            printOut = new Function( "args", printOut.replace( /args/, argsArray.join(",") ) );

            printOut(arguments);
        }
    },


    /**
     * Firing functions and bindings and other important stuff
    **/
    init: function(e) {

        if ( $("#the-planner-form").length ) {
            Onyx.projectPlanner();
            if ( $("body").data("form-completed") == "yes" ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    Onyx.plannerShowSuccess(true)
            }, 800)
            }
        }
    },


    /**
     * Project planner
    **/
    projectPlanner: function() {

        Onyx.initDropzone();

        var checkedValues = [];

        // Add default checked service
        $('input[name="planner_project_type_checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $(this).val();
            checkedValues.push($(this).val())
        });

        $('input[name="planner_project_type"]').val(checkedValues.join(", "));

        $('div.type-selection').each(function() {

            $(this).on("click", function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                if ( $(this).find('input[checked]').length ) {
                    checkedValues.splice( $.inArray($(this).find('input[checked]').val(), checkedValues), 1 );
                    $(this).find('input[checked]').removeAttr('checked');
                    $('input[name="planner_project_type"]').val(checkedValues);

                    Onyx.log($.inArray($(this).find('input[name="planner_project_type_checkbox"]').val(), checkedValues));
                    Onyx.log(checkedValues);
                } else {
                    $(this).find('input[name="planner_project_type_checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
                    checkedValues.push($(this).find('input[name="planner_project_type_checkbox"]').val());
                    $('input[name="planner_project_type"]').val(checkedValues.join(", "));

                    Onyx.log(checkedValues);
                    Onyx.log($.inArray($(this).find('input[name="planner_project_type_checkbox"]').val(), checkedValues));
                }

            });

        });

        var sendingForm = false;

        $("form#the-planner-form").bind("submit", function(e) {
            
            e.preventDefault();

            // Check every thing is valid
            $('form#the-planner-form').find(".validate").each(function() {
                sendingForm = 0 != Onyx.plannerValidate($(this));
            });

            if (sendingForm) {
                $(".error-msg").stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function () { $(this).hide() });

                if ( matchMedia("only screen and (max-height: 1023px)").matches || matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 600px)").matches ) {
                    $("html,body").stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 500);
                }

                Onyx.plannerShowSpinner();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: window.location + "/send_form.php",
                    data: $("#the-planner-form").serialize()
                }).done(function (status, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    Onyx.log("Planner form status: " + status);
                    Onyx.log("Planner form textStatus: " + textStatus);
                    Onyx.log(jqXHR);

                    if ( jqXHR.status == 200 && textStatus == 'success' ) {
                        Onyx.plannerShowSuccess();
                    } else {
                        Onyx.plannerShowSpinner(false);
                        alert("Something went wrong");
                    }

                });
            } else {
                $(".error-msg").stop().css({
                    display: "block",
                    opacity: 0
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300), false
            }
        });

    },
    plannerShowSpinner: function(showSpinner) {
        if ("undefined" == typeof showSpinner) var showSpinner = true;

        if ( showSpinner ) {
            $(".form-controls, .fields-group").stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 400, function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $(".form-spinner").stop().css({
                    display: "block",
                    opacity: 0
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300)
            });
        } else {
            $(".form-spinner").stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 300, function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $(".form-controls, .fields-group").stop().css({
                    display: "block",
                    opacity: 0
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 400)
            });
        }
    },
    plannerShowSuccess: function(showSuccess) {
        if ("undefined" == typeof showSuccess) var showSuccess = false;

        var showThankyou = function() {
            $(".form-spinner").stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 150, function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $(".form-thankyou-wrap").stop().css({
                    display: "block",
                    opacity: 0
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300)
            })
        };
        showSuccess ? $(".form-controls").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 400, function() {
            $(this).hide(), showThankyou()
        }) : showThankyou()
    },


    /**
     * Upload button
    **/
    dropzone_active: false,
    updateDropzoneCount: function() {
        var uploadedCount = $(".dz-preview.dz-success").length,
            finalText = "";

        if ( uploadedCount == 1 ) {
            finalText = uploadedCount + " Archivo Subido.";
        } else if ( uploadedCount == 0 ) {
            finalText = "No subiste ningún archivo.";   
        } else {
            finalText = uploadedCount + " Archivos Subidos.";
        }

        $(".total-uploaded").text(finalText)
    },
    initDropzone: function(e) {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        Dropzone.options.plannerFilesDropzone = {
            paramName: "form_file",
            maxFilesize: 10,
            maxFiles: 5,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.tsv,.ppt,.pptx,.pages,.odt,.rtf",
            url: window.location + "/file-upload.php",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            forceFallback: false,
            clickable: true,

            /**
             * The text used before any files are dropped.
             */
            dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload.", // Default: Drop files here to upload

            /**
             * The text that replaces the default message text it the browser is not supported.
             */
            dictFallbackMessage: "Your browser does not support drag'n'drop file uploads.", // Default: Your browser does not support drag'n'drop file uploads.

            /**
             * If the filesize is too big.
             * `{{filesize}}` and `{{maxFilesize}}` will be replaced with the respective configuration values.
             */
            dictFileTooBig: "File is too big ({{filesize}}MiB). Max filesize: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.", // Default: File is too big ({{filesize}}MiB). Max filesize: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.

            /**
             * If the file doesn't match the file type.
             */
            dictInvalidFileType: "You can't upload files of this type.", // Default: You can't upload files of this type.

            /**
             * If the server response was invalid.
             * `{{statusCode}}` will be replaced with the servers status code.
             */
            dictResponseError: "Server responded with {{statusCode}} code.", // Default: Server responded with {{statusCode}} code.

            /**
             * If `addRemoveLinks` is true, the text to be used for the cancel upload link.
             */
            dictCancelUpload: "Cancel upload.", // Default: Cancel upload

            /**
             * The text that is displayed if an upload was manually canceled
             */
            dictUploadCanceled: "Upload canceled.", // Default: Upload canceled.

            /**
             * If `addRemoveLinks` is true, the text to be used for confirmation when cancelling upload.
             */
            dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?", // Default: Are you sure you want to cancel this upload?

            /**
             * If `addRemoveLinks` is true, the text to be used to remove a file.
             */
            dictRemoveFile: "Remove file", // Default: Remove file

            /**
             * If this is not null, then the user will be prompted before removing a file.
             */
            dictRemoveFileConfirmation: null, // Default: null

            /**
             * Displayed if `maxFiles` is st and exceeded.
             * The string `{{maxFiles}}` will be replaced by the configuration value.
             */
            dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You can not upload any more files.", // Default: You can not upload any more files.

            /**
             * Allows you to translate the different units. Starting with `tb` for terabytes and going down to
             * `b` for bytes.
             */
            dictFileSizeUnits: {tb: "TB", gb: "GB", mb: "MB", kb: "KB", b: "b"},

            init: function() {
                Onyx.dropzone_active = true;
                $("input[name=form_file]").remove();

                this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                    $('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    Onyx.updateDropzoneCount();
                });

                this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                    Onyx.log('Start removing file!');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: window.location + "/file-upload.php",
                        data: {
                            target_file: file.upload_ticket,
                            delete_file: 1
                        },
                        sucess: function(jqXHR, textStatus){},
                        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                            var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);

                            // Handle success
                            if (response.status === 'success') {
                                Onyx.log('Success: ' + response.info);
                            }

                            // Handle error
                            else {
                                Onyx.log('Error: ' + response.info);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    var inputField = $("input[name=form_files_list]"),
                        filesArray = inputField.val().split(","),
                        fileIndex = $.inArray(file.upload_ticket, filesArray);

                    fileIndex !== -1 && filesArray.splice(fileIndex, 1);

                    inputField.val(filesArray.length > 0 ? filesArray.join(",") : "");
                    Onyx.updateDropzoneCount();
                });

                this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                    let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                    file.upload_ticket = parsedResponse.file_link;

                    var inputField = $("input[name=form_files_list]"),
                        filesArray = [];

                    Onyx.log(file.upload_ticket);

                    if ( "" != inputField.val() ) {
                        filesArray = inputField.val().split(",");
                    }

                    filesArray.push(file.upload_ticket);

                    inputField.val(filesArray.length > 0 ? filesArray.join(",") : "");

                    // Something to happen when file is uploaded
                });

                this.on("complete", function(file) {
                    if ( 0 === this.getUploadingFiles().length && 0 === this.getQueuedFiles().length ) {
                        $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                    Onyx.updateDropzoneCount()
                });

                this.on("error", function(file, t, a) {
                    this.removeFile(file);
                });
            }
        };

        $("#planner-files-dropzone").dropzone();

        $("#planner-files-dropzone .instructions").click(function(e) {
            var t = Dropzone.forElement("#planner-files-dropzone");
            t.hiddenFileInput.click();
            e.preventDefault()
        })
    },
    plannerValidate: function(e) {
        if ("" == e.val()) return e.addClass("error"), false;
        if (!e.is('[type="email"]')) return e.removeClass("error"), true;
        var t = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(e.val());
        return t ? void 0 : (e.addClass("error"), false)
    }
};


$(function() {
    Onyx.init();
});
```

```css
<?php
$delete_file = 0;
if(isset($_POST['delete_file'])){ 
    $delete_file = $_POST['delete_file'];
}
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/uploads/';

// Check if it's an upload or delete and if there is a file in the form
if ( !empty($_FILES) && $delete_file == 0 ) {

    // Check if the upload folder is exists
    if ( file_exists($targetPath) && is_dir($targetPath) ) {

        // Check if we can write in the target directory
        if ( is_writable($targetPath) ) {

            /**
             * Start dancing
             */
            $tempFile = $_FILES['form_file']['tmp_name'];

            $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['form_file']['name'];

            // Check if there is any file with the same name
            if ( !file_exists($targetFile) ) {

                // Upload the file
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

                // Be sure that the file has been uploaded
                if ( file_exists($targetFile) ) {
                    $response = array (
                        'status'    => 'success',
                        'file_link' => $targetFile
                    );
                } else {
                    $response = array (
                        'status' => 'error',
                        'info'   => 'Couldn\'t upload the requested file :(, a mysterious error happend.'
                    );
                }
                /*$response = array (
                    'status'    => 'success',
                    'file_link' => 'Just a test, don\'t take it seriously.'
                );*/

            } else {
                // A file with the same name is already here
                $response = array (
                    'status'    => 'error',
                    'info'      => 'A file with the same name is exists.',
                    'file_link' => $targetFile
                );
            }

        } else {
            $response = array (
                'status' => 'error',
                'info'   => 'The specified folder for upload isn\'t writeable.'
            );
        }
    } else {
        $response = array (
            'status' => 'error',
            'info'   => 'No folder to upload to :(, Please create one.'
        );
    }

    // Return the response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}


// Remove file
if( $delete_file == 1 ){
    $file_path = $_POST['target_file'];

    // Check if file is exists
    if ( file_exists($file_path) ) {

        // Delete the file
        unlink($file_path);

        // Be sure we deleted the file
        if ( !file_exists($file_path) ) {
            $response = array (
                'status' => 'success',
                'info'   => 'Successfully Deleted.'
            );
        } else {
            // Check the directory's permissions
            $response = array (
                'status' => 'error',
                'info'   => 'We screwed up, the file can\'t be deleted.'
            );
        }
    } else {
        // Something weird happend and we lost the file
        $response = array (
            'status' => 'error',
            'info'   => 'Couldn\'t find the requested file :('
        );
    }

    // Return the response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

?>
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="the-planner-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="text-cotizador">
                                <h1>COTIZADOR ONLINE</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img-cotizador">
                                <img src="images/barrita-dorada.png" alt="ubicacion" width="35" height="5">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-cotizador">
                                <p>Envíenos la foto de la joya a cotizar, y un tasador especializado<br>
                                    la analizará y le brindará <b>el mejor precio del mercado.</b>                            
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fields-group clearfix">
                                <div class="fields-group-controls1">
                                    <div class="form-field half first">
                                        <input type="text" name="planner_name" id="name" class="validate" placeholder="Nombre">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="fields-group-controls2">
                                    <div class="form-field half first">
                                        <input type="email" name="planner_email" id="email" class="validate" placeholder="E-mail">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-field half last">
                                        <input type="tel" name="planner_phone" id="phone" class="validate" placeholder="Telefono">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="fields-group-controls">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <textarea name="planner_project_description" id="description" class="validate" placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <div id="files-wrap">
                                            <div id="planner-files-dropzone">
                                                <div class="dropzone-foo">
                                                    <div class="instructions is-desktop">ARRASTRA Y SUELTA AQUÍ LOS ARCHIVOS</br>o</div>
                                                    <div class="instructions is-touch">Subi los archivos</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="total-uploaded">No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="form_files_list" />
                                            <input type="file" name="form_file" id="pp-file" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text-formatos">
                                            <p>Puede seleccionar hasta 5 imágenes   |  Tamaño máximo por imagen: 100 MB<br>Formatos admitidos: gif, png, jpg, jpeg
                                        </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-spinner-container">
                                <div class="form-spinner"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-thankyou-wrap">
                                <div class="form-thankyou-wrap-inner">
                                    <div class="form-thankyou-content">
                                        <h2><em>Gracias!</em> su mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente.</h2>
                                        <p>Te contactaremos en poco tiempo..</p>
                                        <a href="/" class="return-btn internal-link">Go back to home page</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- .form-thankyou-wrap -->
                            <div class="form-controls">
                                <button aria-label="Send" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                                <div class="error-msg">Debe diligenciar toda la información. &uarr;</div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: It's not a trivial change. Where did you get this script? Is it a known library?

Comment: I don't quite get it, do you have a form that requires two dropzones components and only one is working right now? or do you have two forms with a dropzone component each?

Comment: I have two forms with a dropzone component each

Comment: this is the website of the library [www.dropzonejs.com](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)